# How can I get DNS and VPN to play nicely together?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, openvpn, resolv.conf

When I'm at work and connect my laptop with a cable I'm immediately inside our
internal network. So I can connect directly to computers inside without domain
name like: `ssh host1`, with domain name: `ssh host1.example.com` or directly 
via IP: `ssh 192.168.100.101`.

But when at home I need to first login to our vpn. After that I can safely
connect both with `ssh host1.example.com` and `ssh 192.168.100.101`. **But how 
can I get `ssh host1`to work?**

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, I connet to the VPN with OpenVPN 2.4.4.

Up until recently I had it working, but as it turned out I had *all* my
traffic routed through the vpn which of course made it feel like I was at the 
office, but it also added some extra roundtrip for the traffic that was not
destined for the office. So in NetworkManager->edit VPN connection->"IPv4
Settings"->Routes...  there is a checkbox "Use this connection only for
resources on its network".

[image]

If unchecked I get a default route that directs all traffic to the vpn
interface (tun0):

```
$ ip route
default via 172.30.0.25 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enxc8f750cc2555 proto dhcp metric 100 
...
```

If checked the first default rule goes away:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enxc8f750cc2555 proto dhcp metric 100
...
```

*Therer is of course other routing rules that completes the vpn configuration,
but that is not needed here for the problem description I think.*

So after checking that box I get everyting working (except for the
DNS-lookup) and a quicker experiance for the rest of the net (I think).

I've been fiddling some with resolve but havet figured out how to get it
working. I have tried to have `/etc/resolve.conf` point to both of:

```
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

But there seems to be no change in behaviour.

I guess this has to do with the `search` setting in `resolve.conf` but I can not figure out exactly how.

So what I would like (I think) is:

- Get network configuration with DHCP whereever I connect (thats working)
- If I login to the VPN the DNS inside the VPN sould be the default.

What/how can I change, check and verify things? Suggestions? Questions?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Can you confirm that `ssh host1.example.com` still works even though /etc/resolv.conf and `resolvectl` show only your home DNS server? (Or, actually, can you confirm `host host1.example.com` works without any VPN connection and gives you the expected IP address?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question, but: No I can not resolve `host1`or `host1.example.com` if I'm at home and not connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN interface needs to have the on prem work DNS address and search domain added to it. Remote to a machine over vpn to your main site and check the DNS address. You will also need your dns suffix otherwise known as search domain. (ex. if your fully qualified domain name is like  computer1.xyz.com or  comp1.abc.local the the search domain/suffix would be  xyz.com or abc.local)

After you have this information, change the settings in netplan, adding the nameserver (dns server) and the dns search suffix. Would look like this:

$ sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
ethernets:
        vpn0:
            addresses: [192.168.86.30/24]
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            gateway4: 192.168.86.1
            nameservers:
                    addresses: [192.168.86.10] #dns server address goes here
                    search: [xyz.com] #end of FQDN goes here


$ sudo netplan apply
```

Only add nameservers/addresses/search values. Ignore the others. May have to bring the vpn interface up and down after this.

Comment: I havent been working with netplan-files at all so far and I was hoping to avoid that. As far as the `search` goes, the VPN-domain is added automatically when I login to the VPN. But maybe its some priority thing there?

Comment: Actually, in your first screenshot at the bottom, I see the 2 fields, DNS and Search domains. Are those blank by default on the VPN connection? They look blank in the picture. Add the correct values if you can.

Comment: They are blank in the picture, as well as in my environment. The search values as well as the routing is pushed from the VPN-server when I login.